# Maple - normal text instead of maple input

Tags: maple

I'm working with a two Maple modules, I try to merge them. A few days ago I want to copy and paste a procedure from a long worksheet to the other one but the type of the pasted code is "Normal" not "Maple input". The "Normal" code doesn't work, not even if I change the type to "Maple Input" (It changes only the style of the code). So my code looks like this:

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140728/stackover_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

I worked with Maple earlier but never had this problem. I tried it with Maple 16 x86 and Maple 17 x64 on three different computers that didn't solve the problem. I started to copy the code to an empty worksheet. I can copy text to the end of the new file but I can't copy to the middle of the code. Do you have any idea how can I solve it? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, so it might not be appropriate for StackOverflow. Try posting on www.MaplePrimes.com. I do need to see some pictures and attached worksheets in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question, there's a link with a screenshot of a procedure with a copied text. Do you think should I delete the post from stackoverflow?

Comment: I can't say as I am not an expert on the protocol of StackOverflow. Anyway, I answered your question on MaplePrimes many hours ago and I'm waiting for a response from you.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the input can be changed with CTRL-M (Maple input) and CTRL-T (text input). This changes also the type. The line that is for Maple input has the '>' sign on the left. If still confused, you can always produce a new line that is surely Maple input with CTRL-K. It will appear above the current line.

Newer versions of Maple feature the "graphical" way of input in addition to the old text-based input, and it seems now default. If preferred (I personally prefer), you can make the old input method default in a Maple settings.